# trying to see if a point is within 50ft of a linestring

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial, mysql-8.0, spatial-query

I have a database with a bunch of LineString's and I want to see if a Point is within, say, 50ft of that line.

Since it's a LineString, expecting `ST_CONTAINS` to return true for a point that's even 1ft away from the LineString seems unlikely BUT if there was a way to add an accepted error margin that'd be cool.

Here's the query I did:

```
SELECT *
FROM railroads
WHERE ST_CONTAINS(SHAPE, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-10874300.116373 3537642.0497826)', 3857));
```

Unsurprisingly, it returns no results.

Any ideas? I'm running MySQL 8.0.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a condition like
`ST_Distance(shape, geo_constant) < distance`.

Another pattern to do it is
`ST_Intersect(shape, ST_Buffer(geo_constant, distance))`.
Buffer is expensive, so make sure you buffer a single constant, not the table column.

But there is another issue here, you are using projection 3857, so the distance is in projection units, not feet or meters. If you care about precision, transform Geometry to Geography type.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM railroads WHERE ST_Distance(shape, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-10874300.116373 3537642.0497826)', 3857)) < 10` worked swimmingly - thanks!